# Haml: How to set inline style for element in HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

Here is my code:

```
<div class='some' style='position: absolute; left: 300; top: 300;'>..</div>
```

It parses only `style='position: absolute'`, and doesn't parse the other styles. How can I achieve this?

Comment: The answer given is correct, but it missed a far more important point: you shouldn't ever be using inline styles. Define a CSS class and do it right.

Comment: It was temporary solution :) try something and clear all changes. That's why I was looking for this :)

Comment: What about when you are dynamically setting a background image? That's when I use inline styles.

Comment: @JoelBrewer I think that for that, I’d dynamically generate a CSS override file (or use JavaScript) in preference to using inline styles.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

It would have been handy if you'd posted the HAML you're using, but this is how it's done:

```
%div.some{ :style => "position: absolute; left: 300px; top: 300px;" }
```

Comment: It's worth noting that there cannot be a space between the end of the element or class name and the opening brace.

Answer (score 19):

No need to use `%div`:

```
.some{ style: 'position: absolute; left: 300px; top: 300px;' }
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach in addition to the hash one by Dan Cheail is such:

```
%div.some(style='position: absolute; left: 300; top: 300;')
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you are looking inline css for image  :**

```
<%= image_tag( 'image_name.png', style: 'height: 25px; width: 200px; position: absolute' ) %>
```

Answer (score -2):

Requested a hash special case at: https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/787 to allow us to write:

```
%div{ style: { display: "none", width: "50px" } }
```

much like is possible for `class: ["class1", "class2"]`.

Comment: Downvoting because this is not an answer to the question. It's just a statement that you made a feature request for this syntax.

Comment: @Adam thanks for feedback. My intention was to say: "this issue confirms that the perfect most intuitive syntax is not possible, let's upvote it".

Comment: Sure, I get that. I think that would have made for a fine comment, instead of an answer. As it stands, if a user who was scanning answers didn't click the link and see the outcome of your request, they might get the impression that it was actually implemented, and you were showing an example of the new syntax as a solution, but it wasn't accepted.