# How to add !important to CSS attributes on HAML elements

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, haml

**2020 update: This is an old post that was closed due to it being unclear. I think what I was looking for was how to add !important to CSS attributes in HAML.**

I have an issue with my Rails app. I have this code:

```
= simple_form_for @post, html: { class: "newpost"}  do |f|
= f.input :title
= f.input :content
= f.submit :submit
```

It works but dosent look to good. And i have tried to look for answers and I found that you can add this code:

```
= f.input :content, class: "name_of_class"
```

Witch does nothing. I've been looking for answers for many houers now.

Thanks.

PS: Also I'm using HAML and Rails 4

EDIT:
Here is a picture of how it's looking:
[image]

And when I add CSS in Chrome is looks just like I want it:

[image]

But if i try to add the CSS in the code nothing happens.

Comment: if it doesn't look too good, set it to a variable in the view helper. `def classy;  html: {class: "newpost"};end` Then in the view your form can be 'classy' : simple_form_for @post, classy do |f|

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set inline style for element in HAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090010/how-to-set-inline-style-for-element-in-haml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to remove class newpost from the form and put the form in a div with your newpost class. I prefer to put the fields in divs and change input styling from sass.